# Parse a XDocument to a Dictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I need a little push in the right direction on how to parse an entire XML document to a dictionary. My plan is to have the key be the path, with each nested type split up by "->". For instance:

```
<Foo>
    <Bar>3</Bar>
    <Foo>
        <Bar>10</Bar>
    </Foo>
</Foo>
```

If I wanted to get a value I'd just grab it out of the dictionary using:

```
string value = Elements["Foo->Bar"];
```

I'm not really sure how to go through each element recursively though. 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: The xml doesn't matter, since I'm basically going to be accessing it through a path string, I just need a way for it to parse those xml elements to a dictionary with the path being the key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Straightforward solution:

```
    private static string GetElementPath(XElement element)
    {
        var parent = element.Parent;
        if(parent == null)
        {
            return element.Name.LocalName;
        }
        else
        {
            return GetElementPath(parent) + "->" + element.Name.LocalName;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xml = @"
            <Foo>
                <Bar>3</Bar>
                <Foo>
                    <Bar>10</Bar>
                </Foo>
            </Foo>";
        var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach(var element in xdoc.Descendants())
        {
            if(!element.HasElements)
            {
                var key = GetElementPath(element);
                dictionary[key] = (string)element;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(dictionary["Foo->Bar"]);
    }
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks for the help. I wasn't sure how tom check to see if the element was a parent node or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at xpath, the format of the path used is a bit different than the one you want, however you can create a wrap function if nessacary

```
string GetByPath(string mypath)
{
  //process path, and reformat it to xpath
  //then get by xpath
}
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative but not sure the true structure of your XML Document

```
    string data = "<Foo><Bar>3</Bar><Foo><bar>123</bar></Foo></Foo>";

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(data);
    Dictionary<string, string> dataDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (XElement xelement in doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.HasElements == false))
    {
        int keyInt = 0;
        string keyName = xelement.Name.LocalName;

        while (dataDict.ContainsKey(keyName))
            keyName = xelement.Name.LocalName + "->" + keyInt++;

        dataDict.Add(keyName, xelement.Value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void parse()
    {
        Stack<String> stck = new Stack<string>();
        List<String> nodes = new List<string>();
        Dictionary<String, String> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("path:\\xml.xml"))
        {

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {

                    stck.Push(reader.Name);

                }
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                {
                    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                    if (stck.Count > 0)
                        nodes = stck.ToList<String>();
                    //List<String> _nodes ;
                    nodes.Reverse(0,nodes.Count);
                    foreach (String node in nodes)
                        str.Append(node + " --> ");

                    dictionary.Add(str.ToString(), reader.Value);
                    str.Clear();
                }
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                {

                    stck.Pop();

                }
            }
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> KVPair in dictionary)
            Console.WriteLine(KVPair.Key + " : " + KVPair.Value);
        Console.Read();
    }
```